# print out an indented node tree in python from a list of list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a data set in the format of [node_id, name, parent_node_id]. I would like to output an indented node tree. I have been able to do the first generation, but don't know how to keep iterating over the list. I had to use a try/except clause because not all sublists get their generation appended since I can't keep looping.

```
Grandparent
    Parent 1
    Parent 2
        Child 1
        Child 2
```

Code:

```
# establish data set in the format of [node_id, name, parent_node_id]
tree_info = [['5', 'Child 2', '3'],
             ['1', 'Grandparent', 'root'],
             ['4', 'Child 1', '3'], 
             ['3', 'Parent 2', '1'],
             ['2', 'Parent 1', '1']
             ]

# establish root node
root = [x[0] for x in tree_info if x[2] == 'root'][0]


# assign root node a generation of 0
tree_info[0].append(0)

# loop through
for node in tree_info:
    node_id = node[0]
    node_parent_id = node[2]
    if node_parent_id == root:
        # assign a generation of 1
        node.append(1)

for node in tree_info:
    try:
        print node[3] * " ", node[2]
    except:
        print "help"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing a Tree data structure in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242479/printing-a-tree-data-structure-in-python)

Comment: Your data structure makes this tricky, since as written, it's not practical to determine what level of indentation you should be using. If you need a tree structure, make a tree structure, don't try to use flat data structures and imperative code to perform a task that is more obviously solvable with nested data structures and recursive code.

Comment: @felipsmartins: The basic idea is similar, but this code isn't actually using real nodes, it's trying to hack tree-like relationships into not-tree-like code.

Comment: OP, rather than trying to make logic of how to print with your current data structure, I would suggest trying to convert what you have into a more utilizable data structure list nested dicts of lists or something.

Comment: @RNar - agreed, split this into two problems: (1) Parse `tree_info` into a nested structure that you want, then (2) print out the result of this structure

Comment: `if node_parent_id == root:` look at what you are comparing here.

Comment: @ShadowRanger this data comes from a `SQL` query, so I'd need `python` to dump into a JSON like format. Is that worth the effort and if so want to suggest that as an answer?

Comment: The problem is that the children store the parents, but the parents don't store the children.  Once this relationship is reversed, it becomes simple tree traversal.  The answer you accepted does just that with the `children.setdefault(parent, []).append(node_id)` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the data structure you are working with is kind of clumsy for tree data. Nevertheless, it's quite simple to print out the structure of the tree, provided that you keep track of the indentation level of the nodes you've seen so far. We can do this with a dictionary:

```
# establish data set in the format of [node_id, name, parent_node_id]
tree_info = [
    ['1', 'Grandparent', 'root'], 
    ['2', 'Parent 1', '1'], 
    ['3', 'Parent 2', '1'], 
    ['4', 'Child 1', '3'], 
    ['5', 'Child 2', '3']
]

generation = {'root': 0}

for node in tree_info:
    node_id, name, parent_id = node
    indent = generation[parent_id]
    generation[node_id] = indent + 1
    print(indent * ' ' + name)
```

Which yields:

```
Grandparent
 Parent 1
 Parent 2
  Child 1
  Child 2
```

---

### If the nodes are out of order...

If the nodes are out of order, we need to read through the data once to assemble a dictionary of children. Then we do a tree search on the dictionary:

```
tree_info = [['5', 'Child 2', '3'],
             ['1', 'Grandparent', 'root'],
             ['4', 'Child 1', '3'], 
             ['3', 'Parent 2', '1'],
             ['2', 'Parent 1', '1'],
             ['6', 'Child 3', '2']
             ]

children = {}
names = {}

for node_id, name, parent in tree_info:
    children.setdefault(parent, []).append(node_id)
    names[node_id] = name

q = [('root', -1)]
while q:
    parent, depth = q.pop()
    if parent != 'root':
        print(' ' * depth + names[parent])

    if parent in children:
        for child in children[parent]:
            q.append((child, depth+1))
```

This yields:

```
Grandparent
 Parent 1
  Child 3
 Parent 2
  Child 1
  Child 2
```

---

### If you'd like each level to be in alphabetical order

```
tree_info = [['5', 'A - Child 2', '3'],
             ['1', 'Grandparent', 'root'],
             ['4', 'B - Child 1', '3'], 
             ['3', 'A - Parent 2', '1'],
             ['2', 'B - Parent 1', '1'],
             ['6', 'C - Child 3', '2']
             ]

children = {}
names = {}

for node_id, name, parent in tree_info:
    children.setdefault(parent, []).append(node_id)
    names[node_id] = name

q = [('root', -1)]
while q:
    parent, depth = q.pop()
    if parent != 'root':
        print(' ' * depth + names[parent])

    if parent in children:
        level = sorted(children[parent], key=names.get)
        for child in reversed(level):
            q.append((child, depth+1))
```

Which prints:

```
Grandparent
 A - Parent 2
  A - Child 2
  B - Child 1
 B - Parent 1
  C - Child 3
```

Comment: am i correct in saying that this code assumes that the list is ordered in a way where a parent is always before its children? its a good assumption, I just want to make sure its explicit

Comment: @RNar Yep, that's the assumption, thanks for making it clear. If this cannot be assumed then using a proper data structure becomes imperative.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Although if `'root'` is not in the first element of `tree_info`, this fails. What's the easiest way to handle this?

Comment: If `root` is not in the first element of `tree_info`, then should I assume that it isn't always the case that you see a node's parent before seeing the node itself?

Comment: @jme, yes that is a correct assumption. The real data (not my simple example) comes from a SQL query and I can guarantee it's order

Comment: I see, so is it fair to say that the root node is the only node that is out of order? Could update your example to show how the root might appear in your list?

Comment: @jme I randomized the order. The order should still be able to be figured out by because we always know the highest node (the one with a parent of root) then everything else should be able to be recursively figured out.

Comment: @user2242044 OK, I see. I've added a solution which should work in this general case.

Comment: @JME I took a closer look at this and the nodes out of order code dumps both of the children nodes under parent 1 when they should be under parent 2. Any idea how to correct that?

Comment: At @JME is there a way that I could output the results in alphabetic order for each level in the node tree?

Comment: @user2242044 Have you tried doing so? What have you come up with?

Comment: @JME. so basically my thought was to output the indented node value to a list rather than printing it. Then create a dictionary with keys as nodes that have children and stripped (no leading spaces) values as the children. Sort those values then recombine back to a list. As I start to code it, it's becomes increasing (and most likely) unnecessarily complex.

Comment: A bit of thought shows that you cannot, in general, require that all levels of the tree are simultaneously in alphabetical order. The best you can do is  say that the children of each parent are printed in order. We get the children of each parent in the line `for child in children[parent]`. The idea is to sort `children[parent]`, which is a list, by name, then iterate over the sorted list, but in reverse order. Altogether the change is 1 line of code (though probably best split into two for readability). Let me know if you have trouble writing the code, but I'd encourage you to try.

Comment: @JME, I've been working on this and am a bit confused. `children[parent]`  returns a list of all the children node Ids of a particular parent. But the names are part of that list. So should do I need to then pulls in the names from the original list so I know the sort order?