# Saving a Tree data structure as a dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, tree, output

I came across a post called [Printing a Tree Data Structure in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242479/printing-a-tree-data-structure-in-python) and I like the ability to print the tree traversal.

What I would like is to capture the output as a dictionary instead.  This is my print code:

```
def print(self, level=0):
    print('{}{}'.format(' '*4*level, self.node_id))
    for child in self.children:
        child.print(level=level+1)
```

Which prints something like this:

```
'grandmother'
    'daughter'
        'granddaughter'
        'grandson'
    'son'
        'granddaughter'
        'grandson'
```

I have no clue where to even start.

Comment: Where to start is making a list of the (key, value) pairs that you expect the dictionary representation of that tree to contain. An example goes a long way toward explaining what it is you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple unoptimized version to give you some clues about where to start:

```
from itertools import takewhile
import json


class node(object):

    def __init__(self, value, children=[]):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children

    def __str__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.value)+"\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__str__(level+1)
        return ret

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<tree node representation>'


def build_tree(lines):
    sep = '\t'
    lst, res = [], []
    for line in iter(lines):
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        indent = len(list(takewhile(sep.__eq__, line)))
        lst[indent:] = [line.lstrip()]
        res.append(sep.join(lst[:]))

    tree = {}
    for item in res:
        t = tree
        for part in item.split(sep):
            t = t.setdefault(part, {})
    return tree

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = node('grandmother')
    root.children = [node('daughter'), node('son')]
    root.children[0].children = [node('granddaughter'), node('grandson')]
    root.children[1].children = [node('granddaughter'), node('grandson')]
    print('text'.center(80, '='))
    source = str(root)
    print(source)
    print('tree'.center(80, '='))
    print(json.dumps(build_tree(source.split("\n")), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
======================================text======================================
'grandmother'
    'daughter'
        'granddaughter'
        'grandson'
    'son'
        'granddaughter'
        'grandson'

======================================tree======================================
{
    "'grandmother'": {
        "'daughter'": {
            "'granddaughter'": {},
            "'grandson'": {}
        },
        "'son'": {
            "'granddaughter'": {},
            "'grandson'": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I simply took the extra step with json.dump.                                   `with open('tree_test.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(build_tree(source.split("\n")), fp)`                                     I know nothing of json now, but i will soon.   Cheers!!!