# adding childern to tree stucture and print

Tags: python, tree

I am trying to implement an n-arry tree based on this post  :
[here][1]
and I am getting an error when trying to define a function that adds children:

```
    class node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, children = []):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children

    def __str__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.value)+"\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__str__(level+1)
        return ret
    
    # trying to implement this method si that I can get rid of
    # calling root.children[0].children
    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.append(obj)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<tree node representation>'

root = node('grandmother')
root.children = [node('daughter'), node('son')]
root.children[0].children = [node('granddaughter'), node('grandson')]
root.children[1].children = [node('granddaughter'), node('grandson')]
root.add_child([node((1)), node(2)]) # error 

print (root)
```

I want to be able to to create a tree and print it.
[1]: [Printing a Tree data structure in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242479/printing-a-tree-data-structure-in-python)

Comment: What does the error actually say, though?

Comment: You are trying to add a *list* of nodes as a single child. You either need an `add_children` method that uses `self.children.extend` to add multiple children at once, or make multiple calls to `add_child`, one per child to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name a method `add_child`, it should add a child, not children. And if you add children, you should `extend` the list, not just append the given list on its end.

Working example:

```py
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, children=None):
        if children is None:
            children = []
        self.value = value
        self.children = children


    def __str__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t" * level + repr(self.value) + "\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__str__(level + 1)
        return ret

    def add_children(self, obj):
        self.children.extend(obj)


root = Node('grandmother')
root.children = [Node('daughter'), Node('son')]
root.children[0].children = [Node('granddaughter'), Node('grandson')]
root.children[1].children = [Node('granddaughter'), Node('grandson')]
root.add_children([Node(1), Node(2)])

print(root)
```

Output:

```
'grandmother'
    'daughter'
        'granddaughter'
        'grandson'
    'son'
        'granddaughter'
        'grandson'
    1
    2
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `add_child` with an entire list object. Within `add_child` you use the method `list.append` which adds the entire list object to the list itself.

Solution 1: call `add_child` by specifying the nodes directly:

```
root.add_child(node((1))
root.add_child(node((2))
```

Solution 2: change the implementation of `add_child` by using `list.extend` instead of `list.append`. The former adds each element within the supplied argument to the list, while the latter adds the entire argument to the list.

```
def add_child(self, obj):
    self.children.extend(obj)
```